Python (Pebble) - Timeout Functionality. Getting the value passed to the function from the iterable when TimeoutError occurs
I'm attempting to set up a worker timeout in Pebble (which basically works)
from pebble import ProcessPool
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool, cpu_count
import time

def test_fn(randomNumberFromList):
    # print(f'Beginnging for this number: {randomNumberFromList}')

        if randomNumberFromList in [1,66,3,88,5,777]:
            time.sleep(10)
            completion_state = [randomNumberFromList, True]
            return completion_state
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            completion_state = [randomNumberFromList, True]
            return completion_state


def main(): 
    list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 33, 55, 233, 44, 66, 2666, 555, 8888, 888, 88, 77, 777, 7777, 77777]
    with ProcessPool() as pool:
        future = pool.map(test_fn, list1, timeout=4)
        iterator = future.result()
        while True:
            try:
                result = next(iterator)
                print(result)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            except TimeoutError as error: 
                print(f'list1value took longer than {error.args[1]} seconds.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

However, I can't get at the 'failed' values in list1 within the TimeoutError block. How do I do this? For this example, I want "1 took longer than 4 seconds.", "66 took longer than 4 seconds.", and so on to print to the console
Looked through the Pebble documentation, didn't see a method that would get value out to me

This is very much not related to your question, but probably don't repeat yourself in this case. The if/else block contain two identical lines of code, which can likely be extracted out to avoid repetition.

I basically kept that there just to return completion_state if I set the timeout to over 10 seconds - nbd. But thank you!
